# Aligning different vector features and vector features with rasters

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, datum

I am fairly new to GIS and I encountered this problem concerning projections. Maps don't align despite having the same projections (according to the Properties - XY Coordinates).

I already tried with Define Projection, for maps without projections already defined, and Project, for maps with already defined projections. I encountered this problem when combining feature classes and also with combining feature classes and raster.

I suppose, as a beginner, I'm missing something basic. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: First, you have to learn how to georeference raster and which CRS use for your country. All maps, vector layers and project must have the same CRS.  Which GIS you use, ArcGIS or QGIS?

Comment: Currently, I'm using ArcGIS 10.2. Raster and vector maps have the same GCS and datum:
Geographic coordinate system: GCS_D48
Datum: D_D48

Comment: Try to georeference raster again.

Comment: Thank you. That really helped with raster. Do you maybe have any advice for vector? I used Spatial Adjustment and it works, but it seems like there should be some more objective tool that I am not aware of. Vector data also have the same GCS, but they dont align. It seems they have the same longitude, but different latitude. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Select vector layer and move that layer to known point by mouse, and align vector with raster. This is not popular action, but probably you made mistake when you digitized your vector layer. If longitude is ok, then use tool shift layer for distance you want. You can shift layer by x or y coordinate.